# Convert XML Oracle Form into APEX 21.1

Tags: xml, oracle-apex, oracleforms

Is it possible to convert  the XML version of an Oracle Form into the APEX? I saw a procedure on how to do it in version 20.2 but I'm currently using version 21.1

This is the blog that I saw which will work for version 20.2 below
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/modernizing-an-oracle-forms-application-to-an-oracle-apex-application

Answer (score 0):

The APEX conversion utility was deprecated or desupported as far as I know.  That said, it was only able to create some of the UI aspects of the app.  The application code could not be repurposed and needs to be rewritten from scratch.  That said, why would anyone want to do this??  If you decided to move to another technology, recreating your old app in a new tech and making look like the old is a waste of time, expensive, and risky.  Just stick with what you have and invest your time making your old app better using the latest version of that technology.

In most cases, improving old Forms app is far easier than migrating to something else.  If you want more information about Oracle Forms and its status, I'd recommend using the Oracle Forms forum.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/forms